# Convert input() to array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have input() in which must be typed something like this:

```
[[('Zamek', 2), ('Polonez', 7), ('Wojska Polskiego', 12), ('Słowiańska', 17), ('Solidarności', 21)], [('Zamek', 10), ('Polonez', 15), ('Wojska Polskiego', 21), ('Słowiańska', 24), ('Solidarności', 28)], [('Zamek', 17), ('Polonez', 22), ('Wojska Polskiego', 29), ('Słowiańska', 32), ('Solidarności', 36)], [('Zamek', 22), ('Polonez', 30), ('Wojska Polskiego', 37), ('Słowiańska', 40), ('Solidarności', 45)]]
```

and input() convert it to string, but then I can't work on this list.
What I need to do to convert input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dangerous version:

```
data = input("Enter your list: ")
parsed_data = eval(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the input is *safe* (only you provide it), you can just use **eval**

```
l = eval(input("bring it on:"))
```

a **better version** is **ast.literal_eval**

```
l = ast.literal_eval(input("much safer:"))
```

still in both cases you need to be sure the input is not getting from an un-trusted source

If you can make your input to be a json you have an even safer/better solution:

```
#possible input: [[["Zamek", 2], ["Polonez", 7], ["Wojska Polskiego", 12], ["S\\u0142owia\\u0144ska", 17], ["Solidarno\\u015bci", 21]], [["Zamek", 10], ["Polonez", 15], ["Wojska Polskiego", 21], ["S\\u0142owia\\u0144ska", 24], ["Solidarno\\u015bci", 28]], [["Zamek", 17], ["Polonez", 22], ["Wojska Polskiego", 29], ["S\\u0142owia\\u0144ska", 32], ["Solidarno\\u015bci", 36]], [["Zamek", 22], ["Polonez", 30], ["Wojska Polskiego", 37], ["S\\u0142owia\\u0144ska", 40], ["Solidarno\\u015bci", 45]]]
l = json.loads(input("please provide it in json format..."))
```